# Python crashes after installing paramiko module

Tags: macos, python-3.x, paramiko

When I installed paramiko module and ran my program,it is throwing the error "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
What does it mean?

Comment: That's too little information. How are we supposed to know?

Comment: I'm running my scripts on PyCharm CE application.I used the command sudo pip install paramiko to install paramiko and then ran my script.Now I m getting error like this:

Comment: Hard to tell, go see if you find someone on irc: http://www.paramiko.org/contact.html